# Does every subalgebra of a finite dimensional commutative $k$-algebra has a complementary subalgebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, tensor-products

> Does every subalgebra $B$ of a finite dimensional commutative $k$-algebra $A$ has a complementary subalgebra (i.e. there exists a subalgebra $C$ such that $A=B\otimes C$)?

The analogous statement for subspaces of finite-dimensional subspaces is clearly true. The motivation of this question is that I want to find out which category with coproducts satisfies the property that every subobject is a direct summand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
Let $A|k$ be a field extension with cyclic Galois group of degree $p^2$, $p$ a prime. Then there is a unique intermediate field $B$ of the extension $A|k$ of degree $p$. On the other hand the complement of $B$ should also be an intermediate field of degree $p$.